# Multiple DbContext on Multi-Tenant Code First Migrations

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

Hi i have a system shared on multiples apis with webapi, each api has a DbContext with Entity Framework 6 that uses a single dll as references for the models.

A model Product by example can by referenced from  InvoiceItem in the invoiceapi project that has a respective DbContext.

The same Product Model can be referenced by the OrderItem model in the commercialapi that has a DbContext too.

My doubt when i run the migration for the DbContext on BaseApi project my DataBase is updated or created, but when a run the migration on InvoiceApi i receive a error that the Produto object already exists...

this system is has several apis, each api has a Datacontext that connect in the same schema and database. My doubt there is a way that the migration uptade only the Models of its Datacontext in the same schema and database?  The is a way to do this without make a separated DataContext project containing all Models?

Sorry for the bad english

```
//Project ApiModels(this project has only the Models, this models are shared to others projects

public class Produto
{
     [Key]
     public int Id {get;set;}
     public string Nome {get;set;}
}

public class ItemNota
{
     [Key]
     public int Id {get;set;}

     public int ProdutoId { get;set;}

     public virtual Produto Produto { get;set;}
}

public class OrderItem
{
     [Key]
     public int Id {get;set;}

     public int ProdutoId { get;set;}

     public virtual Produto Produto { get;set;}
}

//Project BaseApi this project has the webapi of the basic datas like products, clients, here i enabled the migrations and referenced the apiModels dll 

public class DataContext : DbContext, IDbContext
{
    public DataContext(string connectionString)            
        : base(connectionString)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DataContextInitializer());            
    }

    public DataContext()          
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();            

    }

    public DbSet<Contador> Contador { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Parametro> Parametro { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Participante> Participante { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Produto> Produto { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UniMed> UniMed { get; set; }
}


public class DataContextInitializer : IDatabaseInitializer<DataContext>
{
    public void InitializeDatabase(DataContext context)
    {
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration(); // migration configuration class
        cfg.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        cfg.AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = false;
        cfg.TargetDatabase =
           new DbConnectionInfo(
              context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString,
              "System.Data.SqlClient");

        DbMigrator dbMigrator = new DbMigrator(cfg);            
        dbMigrator.Update();
    }
}
```

//Project InvoiceApi this project has the webapi of the invoice datas, here i enabled the migrations and referenced the apiModels dll too

```
public class DataContext : DbContext, IDbContext
{
    public DataContext(string connectionString)            
        : base(connectionString)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DataContextInitializer());            
    }

    public DataContext()          
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();            

    }

    public DbSet<Invoice> Invoice { get; set; }
    public DbSet<InvoiceItem> InvoiceItem { get; set; }        
}

public class DataContextInitializer : IDatabaseInitializer<DataContext>
{
    public void InitializeDatabase(DataContext context)
    {
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration(); // migration configuration class
        cfg.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        cfg.AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = false;
        cfg.TargetDatabase =
           new DbConnectionInfo(
              context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString,
              "System.Data.SqlClient");

        DbMigrator dbMigrator = new DbMigrator(cfg);            
        dbMigrator.Update();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Wait - are you just looking to manage Migrations with multiple Data Contexts?

Comment: yes, but i run the first migration on ApiBase project ok, it's create or update the database, now when i run the migration on the invoiceapi project i receive a error that the Produto object already exists

Comment: And really quick: both contexts are named exactly the same - was that a typo?  I've a way to manage multiple contexts, however I'm not sure how effective it is when Contexts share the same name.  It's fairly easy using the Package Manager Console - do you think this may be of help?

Comment: same context name but different projects.... I changed the context name but i still have the same error i think that is no way to to that, i have to create a separated project for the context sharing this with the others api projects. I'd like to divide the context in mini contexts to consider the possibility of change the api technology in the future and consider the DRY pattern

Comment: I will add an answer that should be pretty easy to try.  Are you OK with a solution that involves handling migrations through the Package Manager Console?

Comment: Maybe... there is a way to automatize the update?.... because the app can be consumed by several tenants (database level) and when the apis need to be updated the migrations need to be executed in each data base